# Logging for Google BI Engine

Tags: google-bi-engine

Is logging enabled for BI Engine? If yes can anyone point to the documentation for the same?
I could only find documentation for 'Monitoring' at this link: https://cloud.google.com/bi-engine/docs/monitoring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is enabled. We will update documentation.

You can see BI Engine logs by adding this filter to project Audit Logs in [log viewer](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/logs-viewer-preview):

```
 "protoPayload.serviceName="bigquerybiengine.googleapis.com"
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Alexey. Looking forward to the updated documentation. 
I can see logs only for create and delete reservations but not for the Data Studio reports which are 'Accelerated by BI Engine'.

Comment: What is the filter you use in log viewer? Also, please double check the project id matches the id you use in the Data Studio datasource.

Comment: Same filters as yours protoPayload.serviceName="bigquerybiengine.googleapis.com".
I see some activity in the monitoring chart for 'BI Engine Model - Request count' but nothing on the logging side except for the create & delete reservation logs.

Comment: For Request Count, can you verify that execution mode shows "BI Engine"? If so, please file a bug and we can take a deeper look

Comment: For one project the execution mode column is visible in the Cloud monitoring chart for 'Request count'. For another project, the execution mode column itself is missing in the monitoring chart. Filed a bug with screenshots. Link: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/158991638